# Android Database Multiple Selection

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have this problem in getting my cursor return my query with a selection String.
Below is the sample structure of the cursor :

```
String T_NAME = "tableName";
String T_ID = "idTable";
String C_FIRST = "first";
String C_SECOND = "second";

Cursor cursor = database.query(T_NAME, null, C_FIRST + " = ? AND " + C_SECOND + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(firstArr), String.valueOf(secondArr) } , null, null, T_ID);
```

When I check the cursor.getCount() it return 0 but when check the table using SQLite Database Browser and with the SQL command below it return the proper data.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE first = 0 AND second = 0
```

What could be the cause of error and how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which kind of data are firstArr and secondArr? Please, for the god's sake, tell me they are not arrays.

Comment: both are int as datatype, the C_FIRST and C_SECOND are INTEGER as datatype.

Comment: One difference I see is in the Java code you have an ORDER BY clause. Correct me if I am wrong but do you need to put " ASC" or " DESC" to specify which way to order things by in the SQLite query? Does it work if you pass null in for orderBy?

Comment: I don't see that to be a cause, I have used the T_ID as parameter to orderBy to my cursor that returns all records and it functioned correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure the SQLite database you are querying with SQLite Database Browser is the same one that is being accessed by your application?

Use an adb remote shell to connect to the database file on the device directly and issue your select query there. Example:

```
$ adb -d shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/your.app.package.name/databases/your_database.db
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE first = 0 AND second = 0
```

Comment: Come again? I am going to use the Terminal Emulator? I get an Access Denied upon entering the "adb -d shell" command.

Comment: You may need to load your app in the emulator and use "adb -e shell". Using adb shell commands to query a SQLite database on device is documented here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands